# How to determine last string value in a text

Tags: c++, string, file, csv, stream

I'm given a text in std::string that i want to analyze using stringstream.
The text is a line from a csv file in the following format:

> SPIN;5;WIN;10;STOPPOSITIONS;27;1;14

I must create a key value pair (in a map) with the key being a string value from the line (ex: "SPIN") and the value a vector populated with the next integer value from the line (ex: 5). (KVP: {"SPIN", {5}}).

The problem is that I dont know how to determine the last string value of the line (in this example "STOPPOSITIONS").

When i get the word "STOPPOSITIONS" at the next iteration the variable word is changed to "1" which is wrong because i should create the following kvp (KVP: {"STOPPOSITIONS", {27,1,14}}).

What should i fix in order to find the last string value of a line?

Here is the code I'm using:

```
std::map<std::string, std::vector<uint64_t>> CsvReader::readAllKvp()
{
    if (!_ifs->is_open())
    {
        _ifs->open(_fileName);
    }

    std::map<std::string, std::vector<uint64_t>> result;

    std::string  line;
    std::string word;
    uint64_t val;

    while(getline(*_ifs,line,'\n') >> std::ws)
    {
        /* do stuff with word */
        std::istringstream ss(line);

        while(getline(ss, word, ';') >> std::ws)
        {
            //no more strings found
            if(word == "")
            {
                //read all integers at the end of the line and put them
                //in the map at the last key added (in our case: STOPPOSITIONS)
                while(ss >> val)
                {
                    result[result.rbegin()->first].push_back(val);
                }
                break;
            }

            if (result.find(word) == result.end()) //word not found in map
            {
                std::vector<uint64_t> newV;
                result.insert(
                        std::pair<std::string, std::vector<uint64_t>>(word, newV));
            }

            ss >> val;
            result[word].push_back(val);

            ss.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),';');
        }

    }

    _ifs->close();

    return result;
}
```

Comment: You can try to convert a token to a number with [std::stoi](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol). It will throw an exception if it fails, and then you know it's another string and not a number.

Comment: I recommend modeling the text line as a structure (record) and overloading `operator>>` in the structure to read the members.  This allows you to process field members, including ignoring fields you don't want.

Comment: @super that's one way to go but I'd rather not catch and process exceptions. Was thinking of some way to check if the word getline gets after the current one and the current one are the same and if thats the case there are no more string in the line. But its going to fail if i get a line with 2 or more same string values at the end.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews that's actually pretty neat. Any recommendations as to where i could find any code examples?

Comment: Yes, try StackOverflow.  Search the internet for "StackOverflow C++ read file record comma separated".  Although you'll get examples using fields separated by a comma, ',', you can easily change it to a ';'.  I've already answered many of these.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews alright, thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made an example of my suggested method. It only read one line, but adding another outer loop and processing all the lines of the file is a simple task.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

std::map<std::string, std::vector<uint64_t>> readAllKvp()
{
    std::string str = "SPIN;5;WIN;10;STOPPOSITIONS;27;1;14";
    std::stringstream ss(str); // Emulating input from file

    std::map<std::string, std::vector<uint64_t>> result;

    std::string word;
    std::string last_string;
    uint64_t val;

    while(getline(ss >> std::ws, word, ';') >> std::ws)
    {
        try {
            val = std::stoi(word);

            if(!last_string.empty())
                result[last_string].push_back(val);
        } catch (std::invalid_argument&) {
            last_string = word;
        }
    }

    return result;
}

int main() {
    auto map = readAllKvp();

    for (auto& m : map) {
        cout << m.first << ": ";

        for (auto v : m.second)
            cout << v << ' ';

        cout << endl;
    }
}
```